# in his own way/in their own way?

Tags: grammar

Which one is grammatically correct?

John, James and Fred helped, each in **his** own way, to rebuild the village.

John, James and Fred helped, each in **their** own way, to rebuild the village.

Comment: Both are fine. Especially since frequently _their_ is used as a gender-neutral singular pronoun.

Comment: @OliverMason But why using a gender-neutral pronoun when it refers only to a male subject?

Comment: Just general habit. Gender is not important, so you'd just use _their_ all the time unless you're talking about a particular person.